# My Dell laptop overheated after I installed Debian squeeze on esata drive

Tags: laptop, debian, dell-latitude

I've been running Ubuntu on my 1 y/o Dell Lattitude laptop.

Today I installed Debian squeeze and xen-4.0 on it and was surprised to see it cut out. When I rebooted a bios message told me it had previously overheated. It felt pretty hot to touch when I removed it from the docking station.

I've booted back into Ubuntu Lucid to avoid damaging the laptop. I would like to work out what caused it to overheat as I'm pretty excited having Xen on my workstation.

Any ideas on how I can track down the source of the overheating?
Could it have been the fact that I was booting from esata?
Does Ubuntu differ from Debian in power management?

Comment: Wow, interesting. Did it cut out immediately, or did it run for a while? And if it ran, did you hear the CPU fan at any point?

Comment: It ran for a couple of hours and I didn't hear the fan get noisy.

Comment: The cooling fans are usually run by the BIOS, not the operating system. You might want to check your BIOS and make sure everything looks right.

Comment: Is it possible to check the BIOS from linux these days or does it still require a reboot?

Comment: Get the hoover out and give the fans a good vacumn. Your computer - being a notebook - needs this done from time to time and it is worth giving a try.